# C# MVC 4 ViewModel causes DropDownList to have the wrong Name

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

Disclaimer: I'm new to C#, .Net and MVC. This is also my first ViewModel.

I have a view model that looks like this.

```
 public class ProjectEditIndexData
 {
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    public List<Characteristic> Chars { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Cats { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        ProjectEditIndexData project = new ProjectEditIndexData();
        project.Project = db.Projects.Find(id);
        project.Tags = db.Tags.ToList();
        project.Chars = db.Characteristics.ToList();
        project.Cats = db.Categories.ToList();
        project.Types = new SelectList(db.ProjectTypes, "ProjectTypeID", "Type", project.Project.ProjectTypeID);


        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

I have a line in my view like this.

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ProjectTypeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Types)
```

The rendered HTML

```
 <select id="ProjectTypeID" name="ProjectTypeID" class="valid">
     <option selected="selected" value="1">Novel</option>
     <option value="2">Type 1</option>
     <option value="3">Type 2</option>
     <option value="4">Type 3</option>
     <option value="5">Type 4</option>
 </select>
```

This all works fine, mostly. The problem is that once I post the form, the Project.ProjectID value is 0, because the NAME attribute on the drop down list is "ProjectTypeID" instead of "Project.ProjectTypeID". How do I get the drop down list to have the right name so that it posts correctly and I can update the record in the Project table?

Comment: Is there some problem with use `@Html.DropDownList("Project.ProjectTypeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Types)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using another overload of the helper extension method:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Project.ProjectTypeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Types)
```